# How do I drop a RavenDB with powershell?

Tags: powershell, ravendb

How do I drop a RavenDB database using Powershell? I know the name of the database (it does not change).

I have studied the [backup script](http://ravendb.net/kb/46/backing-up-all-databases-using-powershell) and can see that I can contact RavenDB through a web request:

```
$req = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("$ravenUrl/databases")
```

Is there a URL to drop a database?

I assume that it is better to drop the database through the Raven service rather than deleting the files straight from disk (`C:\RavenDB\Database\Databases`).

### Ayende's answer as a Powershell script

Thanks to Ayende for the answer, here's the **very dangerous** powershell script. Use at your own risk!

```
$Url = "http://localhost:8080/admin/databases/db-name"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method delete | Out-Null
```

### Hard delete the database

By default, RavenDB does not hard delete the files. To specify hard-delete, add `hard-delete=true` to the URL, which gives:

```
$Url = "http://localhost:8080/admin/databases/db-name?hard-delete=true"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method delete | Out-Null
```

Comment: For different types of raven installations, like when installed as a "Web App" under IIS, the URL can be something more like ```http://localhost/{raven}/admin/databases/{db-name}``` or even ```http://raven.example.com/admin/databases/{db-name}```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using REST call:

DELETE /admin/databases/db-name

Note that you need to auth a a server admin for that.

Comment: Thank you! Updated question with the rest call as a powershell script.